# Problems converting strings to dates

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, string-parsing

I exctract dates from a big document via regex and want to save them into Java dates. This works for most of the dates, but not for dates in December.
I think it has something to do with the way it is written, because when I change its spelling from "Dec" to "Dez", they can be converted.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat01 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm, dd MMM yyyy (zzz)");

String s01 = "20:49, 13 Jan 2005 (UTC)"; //working
String s02 = "20:49, 13 Dez 2005 (UTC)"; //working
String s03 = "20:49, 13 Dec 2005 (UTC)"; //not working

Date d01 = dateFormat01.parse(s01);
Date d02 = dateFormat01.parse(s02);
Date d03 = dateFormat01.parse(s03);
```

Comment: Please check timezone.

Comment: Are you trying to change the Locale? What wouldn't work above is `Dez` which cannot be parsed and would throw an exception.

Comment: @MacC. thats because your default locale is not EN (for English language)

Comment: @WAKALEY I'm sorry, but I do not understand, what I should check about timezone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see, the parsing is working sometimes

```
String s01 = "20:49, 13 Jan 2005 (UTC)"; //working
String s02 = "20:49, 13 Dez 2005 (UTC)"; //working
String s03 = "20:49, 13 Dec 2005 (UTC)"; //not working
```

the reason is quite simple, you NEED to use Locale in the  **SimpleDateFormat**, otherwise java will never understand if **"20:49, 13 Dec 2005 (UTC)"** is December (English language) or Dezember (german language)

```
... new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm, dd MMM yyyy (zzz)", Locale.EN);
```

when I see where is the code working or not, I can infer, your java is running on a german Localized env. therefore **13 Jan 2005**  can be :

**13 January 2005**  (English Locale) or **13 Januar 2005**  (German Locale), both cases coincidentially begin with the same char sequence....

not the case for **December/Dezember**

Comment: Thank you a lot! I already expected something like this after changing it to dez.

Comment: you are willkommen ; )